# What is an algorithm to generate the following sequence?

Tags: formula, sequence, series

I want to find out the function to generate the sequence with the following pattern.

```
1 2 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ....
```

Where the lower bound number is 1 upper number bound number is 3. Each time numbers start from 1 and each number repeats `2 ^ n` times, with n starting with 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes, I hope it will help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

 int main(){

   for(int n = 0; n < 5;n++){
      for(int i = 1; i < 4;i++){
          for(int j = 0;j < pow(2,n) ;j++){
              std::cout << i;
          }
       }
    }

 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    // These are the loop control variables
    int n, m, i, j, k;

    // Read the limit
    cin >> n;

    // Outermost loop to execute the pattern {1..., 2..., 3...} n times
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // This loop generates the required numbers 1, 2, and 3
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; ++j)
        {
            // Display the generated number 2^i times
            m = pow(2, i);
            for (k = 0; k < m; ++k)
            {
                std::cout << j << ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the same logic in any language you choose to implement it.